# scandir() -> 2 folders -> show 1 result

Tags: php

**Hello everybody,**

I would like to scan the content of 2 different folders and show the result in 1 list/array. How is that possible?

### This script works fine for 1 folder:

```
<?php
    $ordner = "images/";
    $alledateien = scandir($ordner);

    foreach ($alledateien as $datei) {
        $dateiinfo = pathinfo($ordner."/".$datei); 
        $size = ceil(filesize($ordner."/".$datei)/1024); 

        if ($datei != "." && $datei != ".."  && $datei != ".DS_Store") 
        { 
?>
            <?php echo $dateiinfo['filename']; ?><br>
<?php
        };
    };
?>
```

### I would like to realize something like this:

```
<?php
$ordner = "images/" AND "pdf/";
...
```

---

Thank you for your support!
Thomas

Comment: Put the code in a function that takes the directory name as an argument. Then call it for each directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use an array :

```
<?php
    $ordners = ["images/", "pdf/"];

    foreach ($ordner as $order)
    {
        $alledateien = scandir($ordner);

        foreach ($alledateien as $datei) 
        {
            $dateiinfo = pathinfo($ordner."/".$datei); 
            $size = ceil(filesize($ordner."/".$datei)/1024); 

            if ($datei != "." && $datei != ".."  && $datei != ".DS_Store") 
                echo $dateiinfo['filename'].'<br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Zakaria! How can I sort the results? For now every folder is sorted separately.

Comment: You want to sort them alphabetically?

Comment: Yes! asort($alledateien, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE); doesn't work, the files are listet unsorted.

Answer (score 1):

Simple trick:

```
function getScanDir($firstFolder, $secondFolder)
{
    return array_merge(
        scandir($firstFolder),
        scandir($secondFolder)
    );
}
```

Function just merge two arrays (result of first and second folder) and output one array. Since [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) output an basic array (numeric keys), no data will be lost.

**EDIT**

I forgot about directory name in output's array. Now it's more complicated. There we can use another trick:

```
function getScanDir($firstFolder, $secondFolder)
{
    return array_merge(
        createArrayDirectory($firstFolder),
        createArrayDirectory($secondFolder)
    );
}

function createArrayDirectory($folderName)
{
    return array_filter(scandir($folderName), function(&$value) use ($folderName) {
        return $folderName . '/' . $value;
    });
}
```

Now, you should have one array with files and directories from two different directories.